# How can I verify the AWS Postgres SSL cert when it is self-signed?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, postico

I'm trying to clear a SQL client error (in Postico) saying that the AWS certificate for our Postgres server (through Heroku) is not trusted.

The [instructions I've found](https://www.hynkle.com/blog/fixing-postico-certificate-warning-for-amazon-rds/) all assume that the certificate has a Root Authority, and that adding that to the keychain will solve the issue.  However, the Amazon cert appears to have no Root Authority and is self-signed (see below).  Installing Amazon's cert does nothing, evidently for this reason.

I could just trust the cert but I'd rather resolve the issue of why there's no trusted authority behind the cert.  How can I connect and get a certificate that is from a trusted authority?

[image]